# how to determine duplicate rows with respect of a group and then select whole element of that group

Tags: r, dataframe

there are 3 columns. SAMPN is a household index, PERNO is persons index in each family, and other columns are related to trip of each person. I want to pick some rows whose have the same value for some or all family member, and for all PERNO even if some rows for that PERNO is not duplicate. 
Notice that plz that it is not finding duplicate rows.

Example :

```
              SAMPN    PERNO       time
                1        1          19:00
                1        1          18:00
                1        1          20:00
                1        2          20:00
                1        3          15:00
                1        3          21:00
                2        1          19:00
                2        1          18:00
                2        2          20:00
                2        2          21:00
                2        3          19:00
                2        3          21:00
                2        4          1:00
                2        4          8:00
```

First family `SAMPN==1`

first person `PERNO==1` and second person `PERNO==2` have the same time, so whole rows for person 1 and 2 must be selected.

Second family `SAMPN==2`

first person `PERNO==1` and second person `PERNO==3` have the same time at `time==19`, so whole rows for person 1 and 3 must be selected. Also `PERNO==2` and `PERNO==3` have the same time at `time==21`

output :

```
              SAMPN    PERNO       time
                1        3          15:00
                1        3          21:00
                2        4          1:00
                2        4          8:00
```

Comment: you say that you want to select those common rows but in output you show the exact opposite output. Do you want to remove those common rows?

Comment: yes, and it would be great if I save them in another data frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get the `PERNO` for all the `duplicated` `time` and select rows which do not have any duplicated time.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(SAMPN) %>%
  filter(!PERNO %in% unique(PERNO[duplicated(time) | duplicated(time, fromLast = TRUE)]))

#  SAMPN PERNO time 
#  <int> <int> <chr>
#1     1     3 15:00
#2     1     3 21:00
#3     2     4 1:00 
#4     2     4 8:00
```

Comment: well I have more columns than time and I think duplicated accept 1 column

Comment: @hghg A workaround would be to paste all the columns together for which you want to check duplicated and then use `duplicated` on that column. Like `df %>%
  mutate(common = paste0(time, col1, col2)) %>%
  group_by(SAMPN) %>%
  filter(!PERNO %in% unique(PERNO[duplicated(common) | duplicated(common, fromLast = TRUE)]))
  `

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  group_by(SAMPN) %>%
  mutate(D = !duplicated(time) & !duplicated(time, fromLast = TRUE)) %>%
  group_by(SAMPN, PERNO) %>%
  filter(all(D)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-D)
dat2
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#   SAMPN PERNO time 
#   <int> <int> <chr>
# 1     1     3 15:00
# 2     1     3 21:00
# 3     2     4 1:00 
# 4     2     4 8:00
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "              SAMPN    PERNO       time
                1        1          '19:00'
                1        1          '18:00'
                1        1          '20:00'
                1        2          '20:00'
                1        3          '15:00'
                1        3          '21:00'
                2        1          '19:00'
                2        1          '18:00'
                2        2          '20:00'
                2        2          '21:00'
                2        3          '19:00'
                2        3          '21:00'
                2        4          '1:00'
                2        4          '8:00'",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Error in duplicated.default(start_hr, start_min, TRPDUR, ACTDUR, fromLast = TRUE) : 
  hash table is full

Comment: I just added more column next to time

Comment: @hghg If my answer works on your example data frame, but not on your real-world data frame. That means your example data frame is not representing your real-world data frame well. Please consider asking a new question with proper examples.

Comment: I just have more columns than time, my question is exactly the same. So if I put more columns next to time in your code it will not work?

Comment: I don't know what you want to achieve.

Comment: I just change time with more columns to determine duplicate rows:

Comment: mutate(D = !duplicated(start_hr,start_min,TRPDUR,ACTDUR) & !duplicated(start_hr,start_min,TRPDUR,ACTDUR, fromLast = TRUE)) %>%

Comment: If your code works for single column to determine duplicate rows , let me know I will put them in question

Comment: the duplicated function is for one vector only.

Comment: so how should I do if there are more?

Comment: This is hard to demonstrate using comments.

Comment: ok first I will check if your code works for single column or not

Answer (score 1):

An option with `anti_join`

```
library(dplyr)
anti_join(df1, df1[duplicated(df1[c(1, 3)])|duplicated(df1[c(1, 3)], 
      fromLast = TRUE), c("SAMPN", "PERNO")])
#     SAMPN PERNO  time
#1     1     3 15:00
#2     1     3 21:00
#3     2     4  1:00
#4     2     4  8:00
```

---

Or with only `tidyverse` syntax

```
df1 %>% 
   group_by(SAMPN, time) %>%
   filter(n() > 1) %>% 
   ungroup %>% 
   select(-time) %>% 
   anti_join(df1, .)
```

---

Or another single line option is a join with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[!(df1[df1[, .I[.N > 1], .(SAMPN, time)]$V1, 
             .(SAMPN, PERNO)]), on = .(SAMPN, PERNO)]
#  SAMPN PERNO  time
#1:     1     3 15:00
#2:     1     3 21:00
#3:     2     4  1:00
#4:     2     4  8:00
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
subset(df1, ! paste(SAMPN, PERNO) %in% do.call(paste, subset(df1, 
      ave(seq_along(time), SAMPN, time, FUN = length)  > 1, select = -time)))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(SAMPN = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), PERNO = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), time = c("19:00", "18:00", "20:00", 
"20:00", "15:00", "21:00", "19:00", "18:00", "20:00", "21:00", 
"19:00", "21:00", "1:00", "8:00")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```